# How to discourage a .NET library method?

Tags: c#

For example we don't want our developers to use `string.Contains`; instead they should use `string.IndexOf`.

Is it possible to mark `string.Contains` obsolete?

Is it possible to hide the method from IntelliSense?

Is there any (visual studio) tool catching and preventing the use of a .net method?

Comment: why not use contains?  It correctly turns IndexOf into a bool

Comment: Have you looked at Code Analysis or Style Cop (formerly known as FxCop I believe)? You used to be able to write custom rules for code analyzing.

Comment: Look into Roslyn code analyzers.

Comment: @KeithNicholas - I am guessing (*because the OP mentioned IndexOf is preferred*) because you can't directly pass an `StringComparison` instance.

Comment: `string.Contains` was just an example..

Comment: @lgor string.Contains was just an example..

Answer (score 5):

There are a few approaches you can take.

1. Talk to your team, discuss why `string.IndexOf` is preferred.
2. Use `pull requests` to review code before merge to master (assuming you're using `git`).

If you want feedback whilst coding, you can implement [Convention Tests](https://github.com/TestStack/TestStack.ConventionTests) or as suggested in the comments a [Rosylyn Analyser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt162308.aspx).

I recently wrote a Rosylyn Analyser for my [DateTimeProvider](https://github.com/dennisroche/DateTimeProvider) package - the analyser picks up usages of `DateTime` and suggests `DateTimeProvider`.